# How to change legends in multiple choropleth map using Mapbox

Tags: javascript, mapbox

I've created a multiple choropleth map using the [Mapbox tutorial](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/choropleth-joined-data-multiple-variables/), and would like to switch out the legends based on what the current data layer is.

This is the function I am trying to use to change the legend:

```
function changeLegend() {
    var previousLegend = $('.map-legends').html()
    map.legendControl.removeLegend(previousLegend)
    map.legendControl.addLegend(getLegendHTML());
}
```

But it does not remove the legends properly, it just adds them on top of each other. When I remove the legends using jQuery instead of `map.legendControl.removeLegend`, the previous legend gets removed, but when I then call `map.legendControl.addLegend`, it adds 2 legends even though the function that generates the legend html is only hit once.

Could someone please help me get the legends removed and added properly?

Comment: Does it have an `id` you can select it by? With selecting it by class, that might be causing an issue. Also, where is that function in your code? I cloned your repo, but I can't find it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I checked how [`L.mapbox.legendControl`](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v2.4.0/l-mapbox-legendcontrol/) works I think I may have a reason of your issue, let me first explain how it works under the hood

- `map.legendControl._legends` is an object which saves legends as as keys, the value is the quantity of equal strings added through `map.legendControl.addLegend`, similarly `map.legendControl.removeLegend` decrements the value of the given key if it exists

e.g.

```
// at this point:
//   map.legendControl._legends = {}

map.legendControl.addLegend('<span>hello world</span>')
// at this point:
//   map.legendControl._legends = {
//     '<span>hello world</span>': 1
//   }

map.legendControl.addLegend('random string')
// at this point:
//   map.legendControl._legends = {
//     '<span>hello world</span>': 1,
//     'random string': 1
//   }

map.legendControl.addLegend('random string')
// at this point:
//   map.legendControl._legends = {
//     '<span>hello world</span>': 1,
//     'random string': 2
//   }

map.legendControl.removeLegend('random string')
// at this point:
//   map.legendControl._legends = {
//     '<span>hello world</span>': 1,
//     'random string': 1
//   }
```

Now that we know how it saves them, lets see how it renders them (this is done automatically every time you `addLegend` or `removeLegend` through its `_update` method

- it iterates the `_legend` object, for each key found it will wrap the element with `<div class="map-legend wax-legend"></div>` and render it **once per key** (it actually uses `_legend[some key]` as a simple counter, it doesn't use it to render stuff)

Important note: if there's html in the key it will be sanitized first

The above example will then be rendered as

```
<div class="map-legend wax-legend"><span>hello world</span></div>
<div class="map-legend wax-legend">random string</div>
```

This is the content of the `.map-legends` container

```
<div class="map-legends wax-legends leaflet-control">
  <div class="map-legend wax-legend"><span>hello world</span></div>
  <div class="map-legend wax-legend">random string</div>
</div>
```

Back to your code you're doing `var previousLegend = $('.map-legends').html()` which as seen above will return you your legends **wrapped inside** `<div class="map-legend">` and they won't be removed

A simple solution is to avoid using `$('.map-legends').html()` to get the previous inserted html, instead save it in a variable like this

```
var previousLegend;
function changeLegend() {
  if (previousLegend) map.legendControl.removeLegend(previousLegend)
  var newLegend = getLegendHTML();
  map.legendControl.addLegend(newLegend);
  previousLegend = newLegend;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This was exactly what was going on. I really appreciate your explanation and solution. Where did you find how `L.mapbox.legendControl` works under the hood with `map.legendControl._legends`?

Comment: @july I went to the documentation site and opened the console, then run some commands like `var x = L.mapbox.legendControl()` and `console.dir(x)`, with that you get enough info to realize that the `x._update()` method uses that private variable, to see the contents of that function I did `x_.update.toString()` and that's it :)